# NodeJS Two "Require" Parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js

This isn't really a code-heavy question since it's more of a concept-type.

```
var args = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2), {string: "name"});
```

How does the code above work? I understand that I am including the minimist library in from the NPM but I don't quite understand why there's (process.argv.slice(2)). There are two open close parentheses over them.

I don't know how this process is called in Javascript. Is there any name for this form of usage ('minimist')(process.argv.slice....)?

Comment: The require statement returns the module.exports defined in the "minimist" module, which is a function, and the parentheses applies the function with 2 parameters. The return value is stored in the "args" variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to:

```
var minimist = require('minimist');
var args = minimist(process.argv.slice(2), {string: "name"});
```

This means, the second parenthesis of your code is actually calling `minimist` (or rather the function exported by the `minimist` module) with two arguments:

1. `process.argv.slice(2)`: all the arguments from the command line
2. `{string: "name"}`: The options object

I'm not aware of any official name.